# change an imageView to foreground and background in Android

Tags: android, background, foreground

I have two `ImageViews imageView1, imageView2` and they are partially **intersected**, I want with an `OnClick` or `onTouch` on one of theme it will be on **foreground** and the other one at the **background** relative to the other one and vice versa.

I just need the function like `setOnForeGround` (which does not exist) to call it for this raison.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have the same parent, you should be able to use View.bringToFront() on either ImageView to bring it to the foreground.

Comment: Not really. Take a look at the documentation in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: @Matt can I just set it in front with one level, I mean not until the front

Comment: Sorry I thought that I have a connexion problem

Answer (score 1):

bringToFront(), give this a try :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront%28%29

Answer (score 1):

Ok Here is trick to do that, First create a FrameLayout and put images into that in order for four images like

```
1) image1 
2) image2

3) image2
4) image1
```

By default the visibity of 3) and 4) will be hidden. 1) and 2) is visible. 
When user click 2) : make 1) and 2) hidden and show 3) and 4).

Then in similar way if user clicks 4):  hide 3) and 4) and show 1) and 2). Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

using `View.bringToFront()` can be useful for you